# Solace Ingress and Egress message discards?

Tags: solace

Is there any documentation on what the subsections mean under SolAdmin -> Statistics -> Client Statistics 
There are two sections Total Ingress Discards / Total Egress Discards and further classification under that. I would like to understand more on the subsections under ingress/egress discards

1. What does Ingress and Egress messages mean with respect to solace? Is it incoming/outgoing messages from a message broker?
2. Any pointers to documentation on the subsections under Ingress/Egress Discards?
3. What does Message Spool Ingress Discard mean?

Tried searching the documentation and there was not much help. Appreciate if you can point me to the right documentation or share your knowledge here.

thanks

Comment: I can confirm Ingress and Egress counters are from the point of view of the broker.

Answer (score 4):

1. Yes, the ingress/egress are incoming/outgoing from the broker's perspective, that means Ingress are messages sent TO Solace from the client and egress are messages sent FROM Solace to the client.
2. You can find description for every discard reason on this link, on the "Description of Detailed Spooled Message Statistics" section:

   [Solace Message Spool Information](https://docs.solace.com/Configuring-and-Managing/Monitoring-Guaranteed-Messaging.htm#Viewing-msg-spool-info)
3. In general Message Spool Ingress discard means that the broker could not receive and store your message properly on the Message Spool (Guaranteed Messaging), and the reason would be one of the list that you can see in the link of Item 2.

Hope this helps.